# Android Navigation Bottom Fragments overlapping

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I am using a navigation bottom with 4 items in my app, so I have 4 fragments.
the first fragment(home page) contains a recyclerView and other fragments don't contain any recyclerView.

The problem is here;
when I navigate to other fragments I can see the recycler view in the background.
and when I navigatie back to the first fragment there is another recycler view under the original one!

I have used this :
`fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();`

but the hide() method doesn't work.

---

Here is the related parts of my code:

> I have globally defined these

```
final Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
final Fragment fragment2 = new AddFragment();
final Fragment fragment3 = new CalendarFragment();
final Fragment fragment4 = new ProfileFragment();
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment active = fragment1;
```

then

> In the onCreate :

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment4, "4").hide(fragment4).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment1, "1").commit();
```

and at last

> the navigation item listener :

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    if (active == fragment1)
                        return false;
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                    active = fragment1;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_add:
                    if (active == fragment2)
                        return false;
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                    active = fragment2;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_calendar:
                    if (active == fragment3)
                        return false;
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                    active = fragment3;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    if (active == fragment4)
                        return false;
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment4).commit();
                    active = fragment4;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: use replace instead of add in your fragment transaction, you can also remove the calls to hide

Comment: @MichaelStoddart
I need my fragment state,  what can I do for that?

Comment: fragment state will be preserved by the global instance

Comment: @MichaelStoddart so now I'm just adding fragment1 in onCreate and in onNavigationItemSelected I'm doing this `fm.beginTransaction().remove(active).replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment1).commit();`
It's still the same.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to delete the navGraph from the fragment in XML.

Comment: you dont need to call remove fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment1).commit(); should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used navGraph in my fragment in the XML file previously and I've forgotten to delete the navGraph, so it was showing the first fragment in the navGraph in the background.